# How to center a Polaris DisplayText (or how to style Shopify Polaris components in general)?

Tags: css, reactjs, shopify, polaris

I just started out with the Shopify Polaris library.

I have a title made like this:

```
<DisplayText size="large">Contact</DisplayText>
```

Now I want to center that. But setting `className` or using inline styling has no effect, thats a known fact...

So how do I style this component? Or any Polaris component? And how do I center this DisplayText?

Comment: A workaround I just used, was to put the element inside a `<div>` and apply the styles to the div. But there must be a better way

Comment: Just use your own CSS around and inside Polaris. There is nothing wrong with doing that. If you are really concerned, build your own extension to the Polaris CSS that extends it, and maybe you can enjoy the fruits of your labour that way too, as the Polaris CSS does not change heavy during updates.

Answer (score 0):

The new component to use is the `<Text />` component. You can center it by doing something like this:

```
import { Text } from "@shopify/polaris";

...

return (
  ...
  <Text variant="headingLg" as="p" alignment="center">Contact</Text>
  ...
);
```

https://polaris.shopify.com/components/typography/text#displaytext